# Can I delete values using edit()?

Tags: r

Running: 
R 3.2.2;
R Studio 0.99.484;
Windows 10

Simple code like below:

```
z<-data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4))
edit(z)
```

When I open up the R editor, I see I can edit or add to cells. However, I cannot delete rows or columns. I know I can delete individual cells by clicking edit->delete, but this just gives a `NULL`. Is there a way to actually delete values in the editor?

Note: I realize that something like 
    `z<-z[1]` 
would probably be easier, but I'm relatively new to R and trying to understand when and how to use the `edit()` function.

Comment: Tell whoever introduced `edit()` to you to give you your money back

Comment: You can delete individual values with `edit()` by changing the value to `NA`. But you should consider using best practices for data manipulation.

Comment: As Pierre is implying, yes, you can. But you **never** should.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to remove the second row,

```
z[-2, , drop=FALSE]
```

or first column

```
z[-1]
```

Also, removing values to a particular cell implies creating a missing value i.e. `NA`

```
 z[2,1] <- NA
```

creates the 2nd row, 1st column as NA.